# Enemy rotates very strangely

Tags: actionscript-3, rotation

I have this problem: there is this enemy which rotates to my player. While "orbiting" the enemy with my player I can see that the enemy is rotating towards my player.

And then the enemy suddenly turns around 360 degrees and facing to my player again. I don't know why it does this strange 360 degree turn but it happens every time when I orbit the enemy for a few seconds. I don't know where the problem might be.

```
tempEnemy.dX = tempEnemy.x - player.x;
tempEnemy.dY = tempEnemy.y - player.y;
                        
tempEnemy.rotateTo = toDegrees(getRadians(tempEnemy.dX, tempEnemy.dY));
                        
                        
                        
if(tempEnemy.frame < 0) tempEnemy.frame += 360;
if(tempEnemy.frame > 359) tempEnemy.frame -= 360;
                        
                        
tempEnemy.trueRotation = int((tempEnemy.rotateTo - tempEnemy.frame) / tempEnemy.rotateSpeed);
                        
tempEnemy.vX += (player.x - tempEnemy.x) / tempEnemy._speed;
tempEnemy.vY += (player.y - tempEnemy.y) / tempEnemy._speed;
         
tempEnemy.vX *= tempEnemy.decay;
tempEnemy.vY *= tempEnemy.decay;
```

Update:

```
private function toDegrees(radians:Number):Number
    {
        var degrees:Number = Math.floor(radians * 180 / Math.PI);
        //trace (degrees);
        return degrees;
    }

private function getRadians(deltaX:Number, deltaY:Number):Number
    {
        var radian:Number = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX);
        
        if (deltaY < 0)
        {
            radian += (2 * Math.PI);
        }
        return(radian);
    }
```

Comment: Could you post your getRadians function?

Comment: I updated my code. I inserted ToDegrees and getRadians. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your getRadians function, perhaps you're passing 360° calculating a reflex angle?

Maybe something like:

```
var degrees:Number = Math.atan2(tempEnemy.y - player.y, tempEnemy.x - player.x) * 180 / Math.PI;
var delta:Number = degrees - tempEnemy.rotation;

while (delta <= -180)
    delta += 360;
while (delta > 180)
    delta -= 360;
```

Compensate `degrees` with the resting angle of your enemy display object design.

Comment: Thanks - I will check this out. I updated my code and inserted toDegrees and getRadians.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've used a timeline tween.  Either use a code tween, or grab the tween I used here http://flexdiary.blogspot.com/2010/04/sample-code-for-oop-timeline-insideria.html.  I don't remember what exactly I did to make the timeline tween go full circle, rather than twisting back before restarting, but you should be able to export and reuse the tween.

If you want to use a code tween, you can either use Flash's built in tween classes or use a library like Tweensy.